# viewing assembly code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-code

I am very new to computer science and will take a course called computer system.
I tried to read a little bit from the text book and follow the examples about understanding assembly code from a given C program.

I got stuck when trying to view the assembly code in Visual Studio Code. Basically I don't know which button to click or select in order to view assembly code when I already have the C program compiled (I believe it is already compiled based on my limit knowledge).

Attached is a screen shot from the text book example that I tried to follow, and also the screen of my Visual Studio Code output. Could someone tell me which options to click on or select or anything I have to re-run or do in order to view the assembly code?

This is the example from the book that I am following (basically I want to know how to generate the assembly code shown here at the bottom):

[image]

And this is a screenshot of what I have so far in my Visual Studio Code program:
[image]

Thank you!

I am actually getting this error if I just typed the code in the book:
[image]

Comment: you have to instruct the compiler (gcc) to generate the assembler file, use the gcc command in the center of your doc image

Comment: Hi, but if I am using my Window laptop, does the "gcc command" in the center actually works?

Comment: I guess I can't just use the command for unix system since I have a window machine. Anyone can help?

Comment: why do you think gcc on Windows has different command line flags

Comment: I saw your last pic. I looked at the docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). GCC is not on VS Code by default. I did this w/o VS Code. Take a look at this dropbox [pic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4p30fv465t3m7h/gcc-s-op.png?dl=0). Did you want to do this? If so, I can guide you through the set up. Also, would you be interested in teaming up to learn more stuff like this? I'm looking for a partner. I'd like to talk more if you are.

Comment: @DragonautX Yes Dragon, I want to output the assembly code from the given C program. Sure please let me know the step. Do I have to install additional program on my Window laptop? Sure I don't mine teaming up lol, but not sure how it will work haha.

Comment: @rioV8 I am not sure if gcc on Windows will be different from unix, but apparently the code from the book cannot be used directly on my window laptop as it gives the error.

Comment: @john_w Alright. First, go [here](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/start). Click "Downloads". Next, click "MingW-W64-builds". It's in green. Then, click "Sourceforge". Save the install file to your desktop. Tell me when you're done. Don't do anything yet. |||||  Here, maybe we can talk too before talking about teaming up. I'm Nicolas, btw. I graduated recently in comp sci. You say you're new to comp. sci. Why do you want to study it?

Comment: It will be a lot easier for you to start with `Visual Studio Community Edition` for C++. When you understand the whole development cycle make a move to VSC

Comment: @riov8 I agree. I started low-level w/ VS. It's GUI is friendlier than gcc, if you're new. But I'll still show john how to setup mingw and see what he thinks. Anyways, rio, can you recommend any tools for assembly? I think MASM and VS's Disassembly will work for me. But I'm wondering if you used any other tools that were easy for you.

Comment: Using compiler intrinsics is a lot easier and the compiler helps you with the assembler instructions

Comment: @DragonautX Hi Nicolas, thanks I have save the installed file to my desktop now, could you tell me what to do next? Thanks

Comment: @john_w Open the file. Click "Next". Use these settings: ('Version': 8.1.0, 'Architecture': x86_64, 'Threads': posix, 'Exception': seh, 'Build revision': 0). Click "Next". In 'Destination folder', type 'C:\mingw'. Click "Next". After install finishes, click "Next". Then click "Finish". Tell me when you're done, then I'll show you how to use gcc.

Comment: @DragonautX Hi Nicolas, yes I done installing. Could you let me know the next step.

Comment: @john_w Type/save your test_file.c file in the Dekstop. Open cmd. "cd" to C:\mingw'. Type mingw-w64.bat. Now "cd" to your 'Desktop'. Run 'gcc -S test_file.c'. You'll get test_file.s in the Desktop. And that's it. Here's a [pic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bzky3q0x19a81s0/gcc-s-op-repeat.png?dl=0). Does that work? If so, maybe can I ask you more about what you're learning? Maybe I can help more.

Comment: @DragonautX Hi Nicolas, yes it works, thanks a lot for help. Oh I said above that I will be taking a course in computer system in September. And would like to get a feel of the contents in the course. They will illustrate many example using assembly language I think, that's why I want to get a feel of it since it seems so difficult to understand and learn. And it seems it is all about memorizing and my memory is not very good. So that's why I want to get a feel now instead of waiting till the course actually starts.

Comment: @john_w Can I keep in contact with you? Email me at nijobias@gmail.com if you want to connect. I completed my comp. sci. bachelor's degree recently. I have free time while I look for a job. I hope to team up on a project someday. But since you're new to low-level, I think it's best to just follow along and ask you once in a while what you're learning, if that's okay with you.

Comment: @DragonautX Hi Nicolas, thank you for your email, yes I will save it. I just started my program, so yeah I don't think I can even carry much discussion at those levels of a person who has a comp sci degree already. But thanks a lot for your step by step help, it is really helpful at least able to open an assembly language file and view it now.

Comment: @john_w Alright, feel free to email even to say hi. Even if you're a beginner, it would be cool to hear from you. Otherwise, good luck with the program. See you around. -Nicolas